# Replace string with Javascript only under certain condition

Tags: javascript, string, replace

I need to do a find and replace of a certain string when this particular page loads, but only if it has a specific value associated with it. Example:

The following strings may all load on the page:

- "0: Here is the string"
- "1: Here is the string"
- "2: Here is the string"

I only want the string to be replaced if the value is 0, the 1 and 2 values should not have the string replaced even those it's the same text as the 0 value. I imagine this would need to be a combination of an if else statement and a replace statement, but I am not sure how the syntax would work.

Comment: What kinds of things have you tried? What libraries are you using? Jquery?

Comment: Voting to close because of this reason: `Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved.`

Comment: If the whole string is `"0: Here is the string"`, then just replace that. No need for a conditional.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it is:

```
if(s.indexOf('0:') == 0) 
    s = s.replace('Here is the string','the new string');
```

Comment: One would need to reassign `s`, otherwise the result will be discarded.